# How to get the cell name(not value in it) in excel using c#

Tags: c#, office-interop, excel-interop

How to get the cell name(not value) of an excel sheet using c#. 
Example: In workbook book1, activesheet sheet1 the cell A10 has "apple" as value in it. If this cell is selected(assuming only one cell is selected) I should get the answer as A10.
Can anyone of you tell me how to do it.

I know that this is trivial. But I searched and found how to get the value(i.e. in this example "apple" using Excel.range) but not the name of the cell.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
r = Activecell.Row 
c = ActiveCell.Column
```

This will give you a numerical address of the active cell

Comment: Is there anyway to find the namebox value? (like A1 instead of 11)(i.e column value in A, B, ...)

Comment: @shrigurunayak I don't know any. You can use converters to convert digits to letters